# Python Neural Network values converge to 50%

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm building a neural network to recognise hand-written symbols. I've never built one before and when I train my network, the predictions all converge to 50%.

When I run my code the error rate decreases until it begins to converge around 0.5, then the predictions for all 21 symbols are equal to 0.5.

My neural network is quite simple:

- It has 3 layers, (input, 1 hidden, output)
- Input layer has 400 inputs, 1 for each pixel (20x20 images)
- Hidden layer has 21 neurons
- Output layer has 21 neurons (1 for each symbol)

---

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import csv

np.random.seed(0)

# Pixel values for 'C', represents 20x20 image of a 'C'
input1 = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])

# 21 possible outputs, a 1 in labels[9] represents a 'C'
labels = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])

# 400 inputs, 1 for each pixel (20x20 images)
w1 = 2*np.random.random((400,21)) - 1
# 21 nodes in hidden layer
w2 = 2*np.random.random((21,21)) - 1
# 21 output nodes (I have to differentiate between 21 symbols)
w3 = 2*np.random.random((21,21)) - 1

learning_rate = 0.01
l1_bias = np.random.rand(1)
l2_bias = np.random.rand(1)

def sigmoid(x):
    x = np.clip( x, -500, 500 )
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_der(x):
    return sigmoid(x)*(1-sigmoid(x))

# Learning part
for x in range(1000):

    # Feed-forward part
    input = input1

    # Multiply input by weights
    l1 = np.dot(input, w1)
    # Add bias
    l1 += l1_bias
    # Squish with sigmoid
    l1 = sigmoid(l1)
    # Repeat for other layers
    l2 = np.dot(l1, w2)

    l2 += l2_bias

    l2 = sigmoid(l2)

    l3 = np.dot(l2, w3)
    l3 = sigmoid(l3)

    # l3 is output layer

    # Backward propagation

    # Calculate error
    error = 1 / 2 * ((labels - l3.T) ** 2)

    # Calculate adjustment for weights for each layer using error and sigmoid_der
    w3_adjustment = np.dot(l2.T, (error * sigmoid_der(l3.T)).T)
    w2_adjustment = np.dot(l1.T, (error * sigmoid_der(l2.T)).T)
    w1_adjustment = np.dot(input.T, (error * sigmoid_der(l1.T)).T)

    # Adjust weights
    w3 = w3 - w3_adjustment * learning_rate
    w2 = w2 - w2_adjustment * learning_rate
    w1 = w1 - w1_adjustment * learning_rate
```

Does anyone know if I've made some rookie mistake which could be causing my output to converge? Thanks!

Comment: Don't you need a softmax for the last layer to start with?

Comment: And you seem to be training on a single example, how do you expect it to learn anything?

Comment: @Julian thanks for your reply, I actually have 8000 training examples but I couldn’t fit them all into the question, so I just included 1 to show the format.

Comment: As Julien said, you probably need a softmax, and you have used MSE, which is suitable for regression problems, for classfication problems cross-entropy would be better suited